# CopyPartRequest class of Amazon S3 - When to use this Design?

Tags: java

I went through the CopyPartRequest class file of Amazon S3 (Package: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model)

```
CopyPartRequest copyRequest = new CopyPartRequest()
                    .withDestinationBucketName()
                    .withDestinationKey()
                    .withSourceBucketName()
                    .withSourceKey()
                    .withUploadId()
                    .withFirstByte()
                    .withLastByte()
                    .withPartNumber();
```

This class have all setter methods (ex: setDestinationBucketName) and also has methods which returns the same object itself which are used as above.

Reference URL:
     http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyPartRequest.java?a=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3

I'm trying understand the pattern when to use this kind of pattern

1. When we need to have setter methods (or) With() methods (or) both.
2. Can we have similar kind of With Methods in entity class along with setter methods so that it will be useful for creating an object
3. Is it possible have With() methods alone and convert the same via Dozer or ModelMapper instead of having setter methods

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setter methods are part of JavaBeans convention and are often required by some tools (e.g. ORM tools). On the other hand those `with` methods constitute a fluent API that can improve readability of the code.
2. Yes.
3. I don't think so. I do not know Dozer or ModelMapper tools, but I guess that they need objects that conform to JavaBeans convention (so setters would be required).